# creating more Sub-admins(roles) in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a wordpress Real Estate website.Website has many cities.The question is that we want to make separate admin panel(roles) for each city.The admin of each admin panel should only be capable to  add,delete,update,select and approve the post of only his/her city.Is it possible in wordpress(roles).

My website link: http://bahria.rent/
[image: Website image]

Comment: Have a quick read through the page Roles and Capability.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities Then see if you can use create roles that would match your requirements. As the thing you ask also depends greatly on the theme you are using, I would advise you to ask an agency to develop the functionalities you need.

Comment: Thank you @Cedric , I think I have last option of custom development rather than using wordpress.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote my comment if it was useful to you